# Jquery ajax function call not made

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problems calling the function `callpage`

Here is the code were I am trying to call the function. I got a label that when click I want to call callpage:

```
$('.gulemenu label, .payload label').toggle(function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);
    $.(this).callpage();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);
    $.(this).callpage();
});

$('.gulemenu input, .payload label').bind('click',function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });
```

My callpage function:

```
function callpage() {
    $('#formcontent').empty().html('<p style="margin-top:20px;text-align:center;font-family:verdana;font-size:14px;">Vent venligst, henter webhosts.</p><p style="margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;text-align:center;"><img src="../images/ajax.gif" /></p>');
    var form = $('form#search');
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success:function(msg){
        $('#formcontent').html(msg);
    }})
}
```

Comment: `$.(this)` is quite a strange syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var slider = $("#mySliderSelector").slider({whatever:'you need'});

    $('.gulemenu label, .payload label').click(function(event){
e.stopPropagation();
       var checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox"); //child checkbox inputs. you are sure there is only one correct?
       var checked = checkbox.prop("checked");
       checkbox.prop("checked", !checked);
       slider.trigger("slidestop"); //jQuery-ui documentation for slideStop event.
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It does not work. I have a jquery slider and the stop is working with the callpage function:     stop: function(_, ui){
    callpage();

Comment: k, i'll edit my answer accordingly.  I'll use the slider event UI.  replace the selectors with what matches your slider code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it works

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true).end().callpage();
```

Comment: How to do it in the toggle function?

Comment: put my original answer in the first function of the toggle, instead of the tow lines in your question. if it works, add this line to the second function:
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false).end().callpage();

Comment: I think you should add the callpage function to your question

Comment: I have added it. I know the function works becasue I call it on some other elements.

Comment: looking at your function, i don't think you need to call it like you did ( $.(this).callpage(); )... why not just: callpage();   ?